# Laravel - Compiling assets, compile dependencies

Tags: laravel, webpack, npm-scripts

I never used npm and webpack before but now when I started working with laravel i know is a best way to keep all css and js file together.

So I don't have a problem to compile css or js files from resources to one output file, but how to do it with dependences?

For example. I installed "sidr" script by "npm install sidr". And now I would like to add this script to my output js file with others js files from resources folder.

So how can I do it?

Thank you.

Comment: you can use  `require('path_to_sidr/sidr');` in app.js

Comment: So as a path I need to pass a path to ".\node_modules\sidr\src\jquery.sidr.js"?

Comment: `require('.\node_modules\sidr\src\jquery.sidr');`

Comment: I check and I have to use this: "jquery.sidr.js". It works now. Thank you.

Comment: great, should i post it as answer so that future user can easily view it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `require('path_to_sidr/sidr');` in app.js

in your case it should be like this

```
require('.\node_modules\sidr\src\jquery.sidr.js');
```